# Strange characters in Console .awd reports

Tags: macos, mac-mini, console

Anyone knows what causes this behavior?

In Console > system reports all .awd reports have characters like this

```
— ÕÖÖ,$90F31FE5-04CE-99A7-86EA-0E99D6B9ADA8 (í0�:
Macmini6,2B16G1036ZUser`êhz áŸˇåÖ,(ÅÄ$0îäÄ† ÜŸˇåÖ,z- àŸˇåÖ,(¢Ä$0yíÇ†áŸˇåÖ,ÄÄ� �(�0�8ÅÇÑ¯@�zû ö€ˇåÖ,(âÄ$0t Ä†ãô€ˇåÖ,…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ…ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ �(�0�8
@HéPZ�FÄ�à�ê�ò�†�®�Ä�à�ê�ò�†�Ä�z- ∫ˇåÖ,(¢Ä$0yíÇ†∫ˇåÖ,ÄÄ� �(�0
8ÅÇÑ¯@zw Ä¯ÆÈÑ,(Ñ‡05äÄ† Ä¯ÆÈÑ,⁄Ä†   Ä¯ÆÈÑ,�ÍÄ†Ä¯ÆÈÑ,�¿`Ë-ﬁ@¢Ä†2(0�R���·øAR
áÄ���
ÔNøAXÄ¯ÆÈÑ,`�hpx�Ä�
```

Comment: What are you locale settings? e.g. typing `defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages` in the Terminal

Comment: @jvriesem I see you started the bounty. I have created some .awd reports with the Wireless Diagnostics app in Big Sur and they aren't plain text files. If I open them, I see something similar to what you see. The `file <report>.awd` command returns `data`. I've seen in an old post from 2017 that .awd files could be opened with TextEdit (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7854058), but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is caused by the Console app attempting to read the `.awd` binary data as text. All computer data is binary, and the file type/extension indicates what those 1s and 0s mean.

Though I am not familiar with `.awd` files I have encountered garbled text like this when, for instance, opening `.png` files in a code editor. Try opening them in another application.

Comment: The Console application is built to read log files. I would expect it to be able to read the files that it lists (otherwise why enumerate them?). If you can confirm that `.awd` files are supposed to be binary and that Console is only supposed to read text files, the bounty is yours!

Comment: True @jvriesem the Console application **is** built to read log files - only some of which are text files. I will edit my answer to remove my false generalization. Also, I do agree, why list files it cannot read?

I could not generate `.awd` files on my system for testing with, but I have found files the Console application would list and try to render with a similar faulty result (for instance some `.gz` or `.bin` files). `.awd` files are certainly binary data but the Console app can't decode them properly.